# How to display specific options in multiple Select2 tagbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

```
<select id="dropList" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
  <option value="Stainless">Stainless</option>
  <option value="Alloy">Alloy</option>
</select>
```

I'm using Select2 in multiple selection mode.  I want to use jquery to display one, or two or all 3 of the options in the tag box.  After a whole morning of searching all the posts on this topic, the best I've achieved is to display one option at a time using the following!

```
$('#dropList').val("Stainless").trigger('change.select2');
```

But if the User has already selected say, 'Carbon', I want to be able to display say, 'stainless' next to 'Carbon' in the tag box.  I don't want 'Carbon to be replaced.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How is your chage.select2 function looking like?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear.  The whole Select2 dropdown works perfectly.  The question I'm asking is how to use jquery to override the User's selection, so I can display one or more of the unselected options in the tag box.

Comment: Let me get you right, do you want to have multiple option "preselected"?

Comment: No.  I think I need to give another example.  Lets say that the User selects 'Carbon'.    The tag box will display 'Carbon'.   But later in my code I may wish to add one of the other options ('stainless' or 'alloy') to the tag box so they display alongside 'Carbon'.  How can I do this without removing the User's original selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the val() using an array (it works for select2 multiple)

```
$('#dropList').val(["Stainless","Carbon"]).trigger('change.select2');
```

See an example in http://jsfiddle.net/a7c20eon/ (It sets a initial value and then adds an additional value to the selection)

```
//Initializing a value  (previous selection)
$("#dropList").select2();
$('#dropList').val("Carbon").trigger('change.select2');

//Get current value (is an array ['Carbon'])
var selection=($('#dropList').val());

//Add Stainless to selection (if not exists)
if (selection.indexOf("Stainless")==-1){
   selection.push("Stainless");
}

//set the array values
$('#dropList').val(selection).trigger('change.select2');
```

Comment: That works @Igor and is really impressive.  Is there any way the code can be even shorter than this?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/a7c20eon/2/ . If you push a value in the selection that already exists, it only sets unique values (It doesn't need to check if exists)

Comment: Brilliant, very grateful for your help.